# How can I deserialize json to create an IRecordset?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, json

I've got a Silverlight client that serializes a [FeatureSet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.2/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.FeatureSet_members.html) and sends to an SOE.  I'd like for the SOE to deserialize the json into an [IRecordSet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RecordSetClass_Class/002500000n2w000000/).   ESRI.ArcGIS.SOESupport.Conversion has a method for going from IRecordset to json, but not the reverse.

**How can I deserialize json to create an IRecordset?**

```
{
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
        "DissolveID": "DissolveID",
        "CatchID": "CatchID",
        "Length": "Length",
        "Fnode": "Fnode",
        "Tnode": "Tnode",
        "CatchID2": "CatchID2",
        "OrigOID": "OrigOID",
        "Shape_Length": "Shape_Length"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102113
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID"
        },
        {
            "name": "DissolveID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
            "alias": "DissolveID"
        },
        {
            "name": "CatchID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
            "alias": "CatchID"
        },
        {
            "name": "Length",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
            "alias": "Length"
        },
        {
            "name": "Fnode",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
            "alias": "Fnode"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tnode",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
            "alias": "Tnode"
        },
        {
            "name": "CatchID2",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
            "alias": "CatchID2"
        },
        {
            "name": "OrigOID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
            "alias": "OrigOID"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shape_Length",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
            "alias": "Shape_Length"
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": 1,
                "DissolveID": 27595,
                "CatchID": 27595,
                "Length": 2781.07146565,
                "Fnode": 26156,
                "Tnode": 26157,
                "CatchID2": 27595,
                "OrigOID": 26064,
                "Shape_Length": 3396.52480192211
            },
            "geometry": {
                "paths": [
                    [
                        [
                            -12199216.57915191,
                            4173685.6358526573
                        ],
                        [
                            -12201719.387905361,
                            4170671.685971223
                        ],
// (snip)
                        [
                            -12201768.97746418,
                            4170677.9241078123
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Good question! How does the generated JSON look like?

Comment: I've added some sample json (with a lot of features snipped out).

Comment: For featureset to json Esri and json Esri to featureset you can see my post http://nicogis.blogspot.it/2012/04/json-arcobjects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IJSONConverterGdb](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000nqz000000)

The operation handler in your SOE would have something like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObj;
            bool found = operationInput.TryGetJsonObject("RecordSet", out jsonObj);
            if (!found)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("RecordSet");

            string recordSetJsonString = jsonObj.ToJson();
            IJSONReader jsonReader = new JSONReaderClass();
            jsonReader.ReadFromString(recordSetJsonString);

            IJSONConverterGdb jsonConverterGdb = new JSONConverterGdbClass();

            IPropertySet originalToNewFieldMap;
            IRecordSet recordSet;
            jsonConverterGdb.ReadRecordSet(jsonReader, null, null, out recordSet, out originalToNewFieldMap);
```

Comment: Not specifically asked for but also common to go to IFeatureClass: ```IFeatureClass featClass = (IFeatureClass)recordSet.Table```

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to what is returned when doing a query [Rest Query API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/query.html), when doing a plugin datasource against the REST service, we ended up deserializing the JSON query response ourself using the standard JavaScriptSerializer.