# Converting ESRI Web Client JSON to Standard Feature Class With Python Geoprocessor

Tags: python, json, geoprocessing

Is there a function exposed by ESRI's python geoprocessor that converts the JSON format used in the various web clients to a valid feature class.

Clearly, the function exists because something is converting these JSON strings into a format usable by the geoprocessor.  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: See [related question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10460/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-create-an-irecordset)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the json data to parse with python, you could grab the lat/longs and use an insert cursor and the writing geometry object found here http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Writing_geometries

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no built-function to do this.

**Edit**: As of ArcGIS 10.1 (Spring 2012), [`arcpy.AsShape`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004m000000) will convert an Esri JSON FeatureSet/RecordSet to a Python FeatureSet/RecordSet object if you set the `esri_json` parameter to `True`. Additionally, [FeatureSet and RecordSet objects have a `.JSON` property](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/FeatureSet/018z0000005r000000/) to do the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Test the [`arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(jsonfile,  outputshapefile)`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000057000000) function.